# computing kernel of ring homomorphism from polynomial rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is there a simple way to find the kernel of maps from polynomial rings?
Specifically, let $k$ be a field and let us consider the map $$\Psi: k[X,Y]\longrightarrow k[T],$$ defined by $$f(X,Y)\rightsquigarrow f(T^2-1,T(T^2-1)).$$
We observe that $(0)\subset(Y^2-X^2-X^3) \subseteq \ker\Psi\subset (X,Y)$, and all are prime ideals in $k[X,Y]$. But $k[X,Y]$ has dimension 2 (transcendence degree = 2), therefore the chain above should have length at most $3$, implying $(Y^2-X^2-X^3)=\ker\Psi$.
However I wonder that there must be a better (in a sense I don't discern myself), perhaps more elementary solution. Indeed, this is an exercise in Shafarevich appearing before dimension has been introduced. Also any answers/comments regarding any method to solve this sort of problems (which abound!) are welcome. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Let $I = (Y^2 - X^2 - X^3)$ and $J = \ker \Psi$. Let $h(X,Y) \in J$. We wish to show that $h(X,Y) \in I$. $h(X,Y)$ is congruent modulo $I$ to some polynomial $j(X,Y) = f(X) + Yg(X)$, which must also belong to $J$. So it is enough to prove that $j(X,Y) = 0$.

We have $f(T^2 - 1) + T(T^2 - 1)g(T^2 - 1) = 0$. The right-hand term, if nonzero, has odd degree, while the left-hand term has even degree. Therefore we must have $f(X) = g(X) = 0$.